# RcppParallel: Code not running in parallel

Tags: c++, r, concurrency, rcpp

I have this piece of code that I basically wrote basing myself off of: http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/parallel-distance-matrix/

However my modifications breaks the concurrency. The code compiles and gives correct results. (Essentially a lookup between two matrices, by the way if anyone has a faster code for this I'll appreciate it)

I'm just trying to understand whats breaking it.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppParallel)]]
#include <RcppParallel.h>
using namespace RcppParallel;

struct JsDistance : public Worker {

  const RMatrix<double> mat;
  const RMatrix<double> mat2;

  RMatrix<double> rmat;
  JsDistance(const NumericMatrix mat,const NumericMatrix mat2, NumericMatrix rmat)
    : mat(mat), mat2(mat2), rmat(rmat) {}

  void operator()(std::size_t begin, std::size_t end) {
    for (std::size_t i = begin; i < end; i++) {

      RMatrix<double>::Column col1 = mat.column(i);
      RMatrix<double>::Column col2 = mat2.column(i);

      for (std::size_t j = 0; j < mat.nrow(); j++) {
        rmat(j,i) = col2[col1[j]];
      }

    }
  }
};


// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix DIST(NumericMatrix mat,NumericMatrix mat2) {

  NumericMatrix rmat(mat.nrow(), mat.ncol());

  JsDistance jsDistance(mat, mat2, rmat);

  parallelFor(0, mat.ncol(), jsDistance);

  return rmat;
}
```

Edit:
Session Info:

```
> sessionInfo()
  R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
  Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
  Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

  locale:
  [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
  [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

  other attached packages:
  [1] foreach_1.4.3       RcppParallel_4.3.14 Rcpp_0.12.1         checkpoint_0.3.15  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] tools_3.2.2      codetools_0.2-14 iterators_1.0.8
```

Comment: You say you're breaking the concurrency, but also that everything works fine. What is broken?

Comment: Sorry, I should've been clearer. I meant what the function returns is correct but that it simply does not run in parallel.

Comment: Right, but how do you know this?

Comment: I monitor my processor usage, also I have a code that does the same thing but without concurrency and the speed is the same.

Comment: I see; would you mind including the output of `sessionInfo()` in your question?

Comment: No problem, I've added it.

Comment: Without input data, it is difficult to say for sure, but I would guess that the threading overhead on Windows is high, and a small problem may be slowed by parallelism. Also, just gazing at task manager is not a great metric. I don't know a better way on Windows, however. Be aware that you can see all the cores being used and the code still runs the same speed, if the CPU cache is being fought for by each thread. Personally, I think OpenMP s a much better supported standard across the board, and worth the effort.

Comment: That's very informative actually. Thanks for the tip and I think you're right, the overheads are bigger. Also openMP is easier to implement for my situation.

Comment: An alternative to OpenMP would be to write the serialized code in C++ and parallelize in R... I'm not saying this would be preferred to OpenMP or vice versa, just noting that another alternative path exists.

Comment: also keep in mind that it's easy to misread the output for `system.time(myFun())` for parallel code. In short, `$user` will tell you the total time across all threads, making it look like it's not running in parallel, while `$elapsed` is the difference in real time from start to finish, probably what you're more interested in.